# Creating a histogram of the number of edges in a digraph

Tags: histograms, charts

I have the following `Code` which calculates the number of edges in a range `theta1` and `theta2`. As seen from this `Manipulate`, one can arbitrarily choose a lower and upper bound for `mm` and simply see the associated digraph as well as the total number of edges in it. Basically, this is a histogram of edges, but a very disaggragted one.

```
Clear[mm, vLabels, selectBetween, subgraphBetween];
mm = RandomReal[0.5, {10, 10}];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1, 6 -> MA2,
7 -> EGW, 8 -> CST, 9 -> WHS, 10 -> HOT};
selectBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
BoolEval[\[Theta]1 <= mm <= \[Theta]2];
subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2],
PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] <= \[Theta]2, 
VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels , ImagePadding -> 20, 
ImageSize -> 150];
Manipulate[
Grid[
{{"Digraph within the range for \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(ij\)]\)", 
"Total number of edges in the interval"}, {subgraphBetween[\
\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2], 
EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2]]}} // Transpose
],
{{\[Theta]1, 0.00001, 
"Threshold \[Theta]1 < \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(ij\)]\)"}, 
0.00001, 0.5, 0.01},
{{\[Theta]2, 0.00001, 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(ij\)]\) < Threshold \[Theta]2"}, 
0.00001, 0.5, 0.01}
]
```

I like to have a histogram of edges in `mm` in which each ban is defined by a range from `theta1` to `theta2`. I also like to see the number of edges on top of each bar in the histogram so that the reader will immediately see how many edges exist in the relevant bar.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We don't use SMS style here. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @user64494: I do not know what SMS style is. I simply cut and past parts of my Code. This is the way I have been doing until today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{"Digraph within the range for " <> 
   ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm], 
  "Total number of edges in the interval",  "bar chart"}, 
 {subgraphBetween[θ1, θ2], EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[θ1, θ2]], 
     BarChart[ec = EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[##]] & @@@ 
        Partition[Range[θ1, θ2, (θ2 - θ1)/nbars], 2, 1], 
         ChartLabels -> Placed[ec, Above]]}} // Transpose], 
 {{θ1, 0.00001, "Threshold θ1 < " <> ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm]},  
   0.00001, 0.5, 0.01}, 
 {{θ2, 0.1, ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> " < Threshold θ2"},  
   θ1 + 0.00001, 0.5, 0.01},
 {{nbars, 5}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image]

If you have to use `Histogram` replace `BarChart[...]` above with

```
Histogram[{0}, {binlims = Range[θ1, θ2, (θ2 - θ1)/nbars]}, 
  (EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[##]] & @@@ Partition[binlims, 2, 1]&), 
  LabelingFunction -> Above]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: this is really very very nice. Thank you.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept.